# How to get comment data from db without special characters and html tags in mysql

Tags: mysql, duplicates, strip-tags

Comment sample data in database in column "comment"

```
  <p>
    Here is the sample content of the article.&nbsp;&nbsp; We hope you fix it!</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Input data

```
  Here is the sample content of the article.We hope you fix it!
```

Input data is passed in query and query will check if input string is already in database or not.

e.g

```
Select count(id) as total from tbl where comment='Here is the sample content of the article.We hope you fix it!';
```

Result will be like

```
total 1
```

Comment: MySQL does have a `REPLACE()` function, but it can only replace constant strings, not patterns

Comment: i no need to replace ,i wants to know there is a duplicate row or not

Comment: Create another column, store the hash of your text inside that column, make it a unique index. That's how you prevent **duplicate rows**. As for what you want to do, that's application logic and you can't control such stuff on MySQL side without aiding it a bit the way I described above.